# What differences are between `utsname`'s field `nodename` and the output string pointed by `name` of `gethostname()`?

Tags: c, linux, hostname

From APUE

> ```
> #include <sys/utsname.h>
> int uname(struct utsname *name);
> ```
>
> where
>
> ```
> struct utsname {
> char  sysname[]; /* name of the operating system */
> char  nodename[]; /* name of this node */
> char  release[]; /* current release of operating system */
> char  version[]; /* current version of this release */
> char  machine[]; /* name of hardware type */
> };
> ```
>
> This function is from System V, and in older days, the `nodename`
>   element was adequate for referencing the host on a UUCP network.

and

> BSD-derived  systems  provided  the gethostname function  to  return
>   only  **the  name  of  the  host**.  **If the host is connected to a
>   TCP/IP network, the host name is normally the fully qualiﬁed domain
>   name of the host**.
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
> int gethostname(char *name, int namelen);
> ```

I was wondering what differences are between `utsname`'s field `nodename` and the output string pointed by `name` of `gethostname()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), I assume we're talking specifically on Linux.

Linux man pages project's [man 2 gethostname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html) says:

> The GNU C library does not employ the gethostname() system call;
>     instead, it implements gethostname() as a library function that calls
>     uname(2) and copies up to len bytes from the returned nodename field
>     into name.

So, on Linux, both are provided by the same system call, and there is no difference.